# Replacing elements at a single level in a nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, iteration

I want to replace all instances of 0 in the outer most level of a nested list with 1. However, when I use `ReplaceAll` as

```
ReplaceAll[{{0, 0}, 0}, 0 -> 1]
```

it replaces all three zeros, rather than just the last one. What should I do to only replace the zeros in the outermost level? I will be using this on a much longer nested list so I don't want to refer to the specific positions of individual zeros.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
 Replace[{{0, 0}, 0}, 0 -> 1, {1}]
```

Comment: What is the difference between this (levelspec as {1}) and the answer I proposed (levelspec as 1)?

Comment: Not much of a difference. Sorry, I overlooked, that your answer included Replace, already.

Answer (score 8):

I am sure there are a hundred other solutions, but this one does the job and should be reasonably efficient:

```
In: Map[If[ListQ[#], #, Replace[#, 0 -> 1]] &, {{0, 0}, 0}]
Out: {{0,0},1}
```

Another better solution:

```
In: Replace[{{0, 0}, 0, 0, 0, {0, 0, 0}, {{0, 0}, 0}, 0, 0}, 0 -> 1, 1]
Out: {{0, 0}, 1, 1, 1, {0, 0, 0}, {{0, 0}, 0}, 1, 1}
```

The final '1' in the Replace[] expression indicates the level to act on. If you change it to '2' you instead get:

```
In: Replace[{{0, 0}, 0, 0, 0, {0, 0, 0}, {{0, 0}, 0}, 0, 0}, 0 -> 1, 2]
Out: {{1, 1}, 1, 1, 1, {1, 1, 1}, {{0, 0}, 1}, 1, 1}
```

EDIT

A word of caution on the solution using Replace[], this will only work if all elements with zeros that you want to replace only contain zeros. Say that you want to replace 'x' in the following:

```
In: Replace[{x, x + a, {x}}, x -> 1, 1]
Out: {1, a + x, {x}}
```

you see that the 'x' in the second element was not replaced. This is because it is at level 2, and not level 1. A possible solution to this is to use the Map[] as follows:

```
In: Map[If[ListQ[#], #, Replace[#, x -> 1, All]] &, {x, x + a, {x}}]
Out: {1, 1 + a, {x}}
```

note the 'All' at the level specification for  Replace here. This means that 'x' on any level will be replaced, but only if the element is not a list.

Once again, there is probably a neater solution here to this more general case. Maybe someone else has a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{0, 0}, 0, 0, 0, {0, 0, 0}, {{0, 0}, 0}, 0, 0};
```

Using `SequenceReplace` (new in 11.3)

```
SequenceReplace[list, {0} :> 1]
```

{{0, 0}, 1, 1, 1, {0, 0, 0}, {{0, 0}, 0}, 1, 1}

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
ReplaceAt[list, _ :> 1, Position[list, 0, 1]]
```

{{0, 0}, 1, 1, 1, {0, 0, 0}, {{0, 0}, 0}, 1, 1}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{0, 0}, 0, 0, 0, {0, 0, 0}, {{0, 0}, 0}, 0, 0};
```

---

Grabbing the @eldo's list and using `SubsetMap`:

```
SubsetMap[# + 1 &, list, Position[list, 0, 1]]

(*{{0, 0}, 1, 1, 1, {0, 0, 0}, {{0, 0}, 0}, 1, 1}*)
```